# Rails has_many dual relationship with other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, has-many, belongs-to

I'm trying to get two has_many relationships from one model to another.
Specifically, I want:

```
class Driver < Active:Record::Base
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :requested_reservations
```

and

```
class Reservations < Active:Record::Base
  belongs_to :driver
  belongs_to :requester
```

The first one is a normal has_many/belongs_to relationship using driver_id on the reservations model.

But for the second one, I want to be able to call `@driver.requested_reservations` and `@reservation.requester`, and have it use the requester_id column in the Reservations class.
What do I need to put at the end of those has_many and belongs_to lines to get it to work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can set the class and foreign key to get the desired results.

```
class Driver < Active:Record::Base
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :requested_reservations, class_name: 'Reservation', foreign_key: 'your_id'
  ...
end

class Reservations < Active:Record::Base
  belongs_to :driver
  belongs_to :requester, class_name: 'Driver', foreign_key: 'requester_id'
  ...
end
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! I had been forgetting to add the foreign_key at the end of the line in the Reservations model

Answer (score 0):

There are similar questions that have been asked before.  See the following links for more information:

[Rails multiple associations between two models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554590/rails-multiple-associations-between-two-models)

[how to specify multiple relationships between models in rails using ActiveRecord associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927986/how-to-specify-multiple-relationships-between-models-in-rails-using-activerecord)